# Discrete choice model with different choice set for each sample

Tags: ranking, discrete-data, latent-variable, multinomial-logit, choice-modeling

### Data

I have observational data of $N$ rows (samples). In row $n$ individual $k_n \in \{1, \ldots, K\}$ from a population of $K \ll N$ individuals chooses one option $y^{k_n}_n$ from $J_n$ options, that is $$y^{k_n}_n \in \{x_{n, 1}, \dots, x_{n, J_n}\}$$ where $x_{n, j}$ represents the $j$'th choice available to individual $k_n$ in that row. Note that the data only contains the choice of one individual for each row $n$.

The difference to a prototypical discrete choice example is that almost every $x_{n, j}$ is unique across all $n$ and $j$, that is individuals are rarely presented with the same choices.

Each choice has $D$ continuous covariates, that is $x_{n, j} \in \mathbb{R}^D$. $J_n$ is typically about 20 but can be as low as 2.

### Modelling

I want to build a predictive model that can cluster individuals according to their preferences. That is I wish to be able to predict $y^k_* \in \{x_{*,1}, \ldots, x_{*, J_*}\}$ for a test choice set $\{x_{*, j}\}$ and any given individual $k$. Additionally I would like to fit individual specific parameters $z_k$ as part of the model so I have some idea about which individuals have similar preferences.

To me this looks like a discrete choice model but most of the literature on discrete choice models assumes the choices are fixed or at least shared across rows. Is there a different name for this sort of model? What could I use? Apologies if there is a well-known model for this, I am not familiar with the area.

Comment: Interesting question but it would really help clarify things if you were to post a small sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MikeHunter . I don't have the data yet. I'm still gathering it but think of each row representing a position in a chess game. For any given position we know the move that one player selected for that position, that is their revealed preference out of all possible moves. Now we would like to model the move selection preferences of all the players and also predict which move a given player would choose in a new position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the typical situation in discrete choice model. one nice book summarized this topic is in Train's book https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2.html. The choices faced by each individual could be different or the same. You do not need to fit each individual with a different set of parameters, but you can fit a mixed logit model in which the individualized parameters can be infered after the estimation. see the chapter 11.