# How to implement nested logit model if the choice set for each individual is dynamic changing

Tags: r, logistic, nested-models, choice-modeling

I think this question is similar to [Discrete choice model with different choice set for each sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476958/discrete-choice-model-with-different-choice-set-for-each-sample), but that question does not have an answer. I have a dataframe in which individuals have dynamic choice sets in different time periods and their final choice.

I am trying to implement nested logit model to estimate the effects of product characteristics and individual characteristics, say price and income, on their choices. I have tried mlogit in R, but it would not work because the choice set is dynamic changing and the number of alternatives is not fixed. I have also tried to find some resources online but did not find them yet. Does anyone have any ideas? Either R or Python is welcome.

```r
individual <- c('John','John','John','John','John','Peter','Peter','Peter','Peter','Peter','Jolie','Jolie','Jolie','Jolie')
salary <- c(21000,21000,21000,21000,21000,23400,23400,23400,23400,23400, 26800, 26800, 26800, 26800)
time <- c('2007-3-14','2007-3-14','2007-3-14','2008-3-25','2008-3-25','2010-11-1','2010-11-1','2011-11-1','2011-11-1','2011-11-1','2006-3-14','2006-3-14','2009-3-25','2009-3-25')
marketSegment <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
product <- c('a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','c','d','e','f','a','d')
price <- c(11,12,13,14,11,11,12,13,13,14,15,16,11,14)
choice <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
df <- data.frame(individual,salary,time,marketSegment,product,price,choice)
```